# Determine model alias or entity type by object

Tags: model, eav

How would you determine the entity type for a given model instance?

For example given an object `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $entity` the desired result would be `catalog_product` as in the `eav_entity_type` table.

If I could find out the model alias `catalog/product`, I could go from there:

```
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->load($alias, 'entity_model')->getEntityTypeCode();
```

But I don't see an easy way to get the alias. Rewrites should be taken into account, so the object could have a different class that rewrites the original entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `$entity`  is your instance.

```
//this should get your the model alias
$modelAlias = $entity->getResource()->getEntityType()->getEntityModel();
//this should get you the entity type code
$typeCode = $entity->getResource()->getEntityType()->getEntityTypeCode();
```

Comment: Looks like we came to the same conclusion :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fschmengler. Right. Now you have 2 independent experiments with the same result. You can consider this scientific fact now.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself 5 minutes after asking... that was too easy:

There is a method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::getEntityType()` which returns the corresponding `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type` instance.

So all I needed was:

```
$entityTypeCode = $entity->getResource()->getEntityType()->getEntityTypeCode();
```

For sake of completeness: you can get the alias with:

```
$entityTypeCode = $entity->getResource()->getEntityType()->getEntityModel();
```

(of course this works only with EAV models)

Comment: ah...you were 2 seconds faster.

Comment: ah... I wasn't finished reading qst. Lol